# SP2010 Foundation Web Analytics Issue on Top Level Site Only

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, web-analytics

I have a site collection in SharePoint 2010 **Foundation** that has several sub-sites within the one collection.  I have setup all the correct settings in the Central Admin to turn on the logging to allow the 'Site Web Analytics reports' and these are being recorded and are working for every site except the top level site.

For example:

```
http://sharepoint/ --> Top Level Site --> Site Web Analytics reports do not work
http://sharepoint/sub1 --> Sub Site 1 --> Site Web Analytics reports work correctly
http://sharepoint/sub2 --> Sub Site 2 --> Site Web Analytics reports work correctly
... and so on...
```

The error I am getting on the top level site is

> A web analytics report is not available for this site. Usage
>   processing may be disabled on this server or the usage data for this
>   site has not been processed yet.

but it should be being processed with the other data.

Is there something I am missing to get the top level site to start reporting the Web Analytics and therefore the site usage?

Comment: Click On Application management -> manage services applications, make sure web analytics service application is started. If not, please start it, then check the effect. Or you can provision a new Web Analytics Service Application.

Comment: @FalakMahmood - Thanks for your response, however I am working SharePoint 2010 FOUNDATION not the server version so I don’t have the luxury of the whole Web Analytics Service... If you have any advice for the foundation version of SP2010 I would be most appreciative